# Combinatorial problem of distributing different objects to three people

Tags: combinatorics

> A painter leaves in inheritance 13 paintings for his 3 children. In
> the will he has specified that each child should receive at least two
> paintings.
>
> i) Calculate the number of ways to make that distribution
> legally.
>
> ii) Generalize the above result for the case of n tables (and
> 3 heirs).
>
> **We assume that the paintings are different.**

My try:

First we choose six paintings which will be the ones we firstly give them. So $13\choose 6$.

Now with those 6 paintings we make pairs and we can make $\frac{6·5}{2}=15$.

And how can I give the pairs so each of them receive at least one? Here is where I think I'm mistaken. I believe is $3!$ but this part I'm not really sure.

Next, for the remaining 7 paintings we have $3^7$ ways of distributing them.

And the total would be:$13\choose 6$$·15·3!·3^7$.

For the ii) part my solution would be:

$n\choose 6$$·15·3!·3^{n-6}$.

If anyone can correct me and give a hint if I messed up somewhere I'll be thankful :)

Comment: Your method badly overcounts...giving the first child painting $P_A$ as part of the first assignment and then giving her $P_B$ as part of the second, is the same as doing it in the opposite order.  Note, by the way, that your answer is a lot greater than $3^{13}$...which is the total number of ways to do it if you ignore the requirement.

Comment: I think Inclusion-Exclusion is the way to go.  There are $3^{13}$ ways to assign the paintings if you don't care about the "at least two" requirement.  Now subtract off the ways in which a specified child might fail the requirement, add back the ways in which two specified kids might fail the requirement.

Comment: You also _undercount_ the number of ways to distribute six paintings to the three children. If you actually needed to know how to distributed six paintings from the original $13$ so each child received two paintings, there is a much simpler approach. But I don't want to say too much about that, since the whole idea of first distributing six paintings is not the way to go in the first place.

Comment: @lulu thanks, I think now I'll be able to correct the exercise. I missed the idea of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: To check your answer, note that it really has to be $3^{13}$.  I mean, the probability that a random assignment fails the test is quite low so your answer should be less than $3^{13}$ but not all that much less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways $A$ (or $B$ or $C$) get 0 or 1 painting is $13\cdot 2^{12}+ 2^{13}=15\cdot 2^{12}$

The number of ways $A$ and $B$ (or $B,C$ or $C,A$) both get 0 or 1 painting is $13\cdot12 +2\cdot 13+1 = 183$

Ther is no possibilte that each get at most 1 painting. So the result should be $$3^{13}-45\cdot 2^{12}+3\cdot 183 = ...$$